# Product detail page $block->getDisplayLabel() not translated

Tags: magento-2.1.3, product-page

On the product detail page I am showing two prices without VAT and with VAT. This is the first price without VAT:

```
<span id="price-excluding-tax-product-price-1606" data-label="Zzgl. MwSt." data-price-amount="247.4" data-price-type="basePrice" class="price-wrapper price-excluding-tax"><span class="price">€247.40</span></span>
```

As you can see the data-label is translated to German as should be, but the second price with VAT is not:

```
<span id="price-including-tax-product-price-1606" data-label="Incl. Tax" data-price-amount="294.406001" data-price-type="finalPrice" class="price-wrapper price-including-tax price-tax-pdp-include-tax" itemprop="price"><span class="price">€294.41</span></span>
```

Everything else is translated to German, correctly.

This is where $block->getDisplayLabel() is called

```
<span <?php if ($block->getPriceId()): ?> id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getPriceId() ?>"<?php endif;?>
        <?php echo($block->getPriceDisplayLabel()) ? 'data-label="' . $block->getPriceDisplayLabel() . $block->getPriceDisplayInclExclTaxes() . '"' : '' ?>
        data-price-amount="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getDisplayValue(); ?>"
        data-price-type="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getPriceType(); ?>"
        class="price-wrapper <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getPriceWrapperCss(); ?> price-tax-pdp-include-tax"
        <?php echo $block->getSchema() ? ' itemprop="price"' : '' ?>>
```

and if I dump it return:

```
object(Magento\Framework\Phrase)[3212] private 'text' => string 'Incl. Tax' (length=9) private 'arguments' => array (size=0) empty
```

Can you help me why this is happening and how can be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the string 'Incl. Tax' was not added de_DE.csv file in the theme.

Comment: This is the answer of the question, why you think that should be moved to comments?

Comment: How did you get these Labels to show? My Price Labels do not show but am unsure how to set them / enable them